# RecyclerView swipe to add older Firebase Data

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am facing a problem with adding older data to `RecyclerView` with `SwipeRefreshLayout` so, here is how i retrieve from `Firebase` and put data into `RecyclerView`

```
private void messageList() {
        referenceMessages.orderByKey().limitToLast(10).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                MessagesInfo messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessagesInfo.class);
                result.add(messages);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                MessagesInfo messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessagesInfo.class);
                result.remove(messages);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

as you can i see, I set limit of retrieved messages to last 10, what means the 10 newest messages will be displayed. So far everything works great, the messages are displayed like that

```
-20thmessage(the oldest)-
-21stmessage-
-...-
-29thmessage-
-30thmessage(the newest)-
```

now i use `SwipeRefreshLayout` like that

```
 private void swipe(){
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                referenceMessages.orderByKey().endAt("-LHUhkub4iaZNNzmtUcs").limitToLast(10).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        MessagesInfo messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(MessagesInfo.class);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                        result.add(0, messages);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
```

and it retrieves data properly, i mean previous 10 messages before hardcoded `endAt()` but after swiping places data not properly. If i dont use `index 0` 
new data is placed at the botoom of latest message and it looks like that

```
-30thmessage(the newest)-
-10thmessage-
-...-
-19thmessage-
-20thmessage(the newest)-
```

and when i use `index 0` data is added from the top of already loaded messages but like that

```
-20thmessage(the oldest)-
-19thmessage-
-...-
-11ththmessage-
-10th-
```

so it is added upside-down. Hope you understand me :) any inputs are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You might try clearing the list first and then add the new messages.

[Android SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic/blob/7efe07bdbffd0ddd8e2ce00f24ecd555af53975c/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/swiperefreshlayoutbasic/SwipeRefreshLayoutBasicFragment.java#L195)

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior of the SwipeRefresh, another option will be handling the Refresh though the RecyclerView

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview

Comment: well, at this moment i used your idea and keeps clearing while refreshing, evert refresh increase number of retrieved messages, but still it downloads whole data every refresh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.